# how to reuse the textField so I can input text in the next cell

Tags: swift, textfield, uitableview

```
public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextInputCell") as! TextInputTableViewCell



    if cell == 1 {
        cell.configure(text: "", placeholder: "Enter some text!")
    }else {


        cell.configure(text: " ", placeholder: "Enter more text")
    }

    return cell
}


public func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {


    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}
```

AM trying to have the user enter more text after they are done with the first cell. But I only get the first cell. I am new to Swift so be gentle with me (:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know in which cell you are, use the indexPath variable

For example :

```
switch indexPath.row {
case 0:
  println(0)
  break
case 1..3:
  println("Between 1 ans 3")
  break
default:
  println("Something else")
  break
}
```

Comment: thanks that was a little bit helpful.    In  public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
      
        return 10 // I don't want a fixed rows the I should count the number of rows based on the user input
 }

Comment: when I am done entering text I want to move to the next table cell by pressing done or return on the keyboard.

Comment: Store you datas in an array of String.
When your user finish his editing, appends the textField data in your array.
For the numberRowInSection, return datas.count